Uniqueness of h-cobordisms between 4-manifolds
Kirby in this paper claims (page 4) that "... any two h-cobordisms between $M_0$ and $M_1$ are diffeomorphic" citing two papers of Kreck. In the latter of these papers the main result is the following:
Theorem: Let $M_0$ and $M_1$ be fixed closed oriented smooth $1$-connected $4$-manifolds. Then the set of diffeomorphism classes rel. boundary of smooth $h$-cobordisms between $M_0$ and $M_1$ is isomorphic to the set of isometries between the intersection forms of $M_0$ and $M_1$.
I do not see how Kirby's claim at all follows from this, it actually seems to be explicitly in contradiction to the cited theorem. What am I missing?
Edit: I dug up the other reference of Kreck ("Ist 4 Denn Noch Normal?" where Kreck says that the above result (evidently) implies that fixing an isometry between the intersection forms of $M_0$ and $M_1$ fixes a unique $h$-cobordism between these manifolds, so that is the likely referent here. Then my question becomes why we get for free in our setup an isometry between the intersection forms of $M_0$ and $M_1$.

There is no contradiction between the two claims since Kreck considers diffeomorphisms rel. boundary (i.e. boundary diffeomorphisms are prescribed).

@MoisheKohan I don't think that's what's going on here, as Kreck only talks about diffeomorphisms rel. boundary and it seems common to omit "rel. boundary" by abuse of notation (i.e, Kreck does this in "Ist 4 Denn Noch Normal" citing his own result, more carefully stated in the original reference)

If you do not think I am right, you can email Kreck, he is a nice guy, will probably answer.
